# Static analysis catch possible null pointer returned from method invocation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static-analysis, findbugs, spotbugs

Using static analysis is it possible to alert on the following code?

```
public class IntegerConversion {
    static int value; // Notice this is an int and not Integer
    public static Integer strToInt(String s) {
        Integer k;
        try {
            k= Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            k = null;
        }
        return k;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // possible null pointer here as strToInt can return null
        value = strToInt("abc"); 
    }
}
```

I'm using [spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) (findbugs successor), and it correctly alert on the code, if the assignment is done within the same method like below.

```
public class IntegerConversion {
    static int value;
    public static void strToInt(String s) {
        Integer k;
        try {
            k= Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            k = null;
        }
        value = k; // spot bugs alert on this line
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        strToInt("abc");
    }
}
```

Is the missing alert on the first code snippet a design choice, or a techincal limitation? are there other static analysis tools for java that can catch this error?

Comment: Did you consider to add Nonnull / Nullable annotations to your code? It will surely help static analyzer to find problems.